# What does "The regime was not legitimated by popular support." mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The regime was not **legitimated** by popular support.

I have two understandings of this sentence:

1. Many people did not accept the regime (=authoritarian government) to be their government.
2. The regime (=a system or policy) was not legally accepted by many people.

Which one is the correct interpretation? If both are wrong, please give me a correct meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Please be sure to give a source for your quotes. I'm not really sure this is a great example... It'd be significantly more common to see "made legitimate". I don't know that I've seen "legitimated" ever.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between those two sentences?  They look like they mean almost exactly the same thing to me, unless you're asking whether *regime* means "the government" or "the system or policy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not sound correct and melba should either be

> The regime was made legitimate by popular support.
>   The regime was not legitimized by popular support.

both mean the regime lacked popular support.